# Using a regex in GNU tar

Tags: regex, unix, tar

Can we archive only files that match a regex. For example

I have three files

```
./a/b/c/d/file
./a/b/c/d32/file
./a/b/c/d64/file
```

I just need to archive these two

```
./a/b/c/d/file
./a/b/c/d32/file
```

Something like `tar -chvzf test.tar.gz a/b/c/d[32]*/file` doesn't seem to work. Is there a way i can do it using the GNU version of the tar?

Comment: `find` and `tar` together.

Comment: I want the regex to be in the path itself. `tar -chvzf test.tar.gz a/b/c/d*/file` gets me the d64/file as well, which i don't need.

I can't use find, grep due to some constraints which is hard to explain in short here.

Comment: That seems like an unnecessary and artificial constraint. Please do explain.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
tar cvf ff.tar $(ls | grep rb)
```

or if you need to go deep:

```
tar cvf my.tar $( find . -type f -name file )
```